# How to identify a repeat column in postgreSQL, where the column has random input

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two columns. ID, and Transcript. The numbers in the ID column are randomly generated. The Transcripts in Transcript are from an array that I cross-joined and unnested, which has generated several repeats of "ID" in Column 1 whenever there's multiple transcripts per ID.

I can't use the usual stack overflow "if" statements. The numbers in the ID column are randomly generated (and there's thousands of them), so I can't just write "if column ID is 'apple', then-."

I have to automatically identify when & where the column has a repeat, and then be able to take the second (and third, if there is one) rows, isolate the unique data in those rows, then append them onto the first row, in a new column. (I'm aware this would generate "null" data in other data rows' columns that don't have the new data. I presume I'd have to create new columns, pre-filled with '-' in them?)

I'm new to SQL, but does 'count' just tell the user the number of repeats for a particular input that the user specified?

Is there any way to write that number into a new column along a specific row (e.g., 'original instance of this ID') so that I can then issue a command based on that number? Otherwise, is it just telling the user how often something has repeated and isn't machine-readable to be used in additional steps?

Otherwise, can I number the duplicated IDs, then I can issue an order. 'if 1, insert into new column 1 row above if filled with '-. Else, insert transcript on the row above in new column 1 if column 1 has data '-'. Else if, put in column 2. etc.,'

I'm entirely lost as to how to even get it to recognise the duplication is occurring in a meaningful way, given the random nature of the ID system.

Comment: Please share sample data and expected results

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)